# Is there any detriment to using an AMD processor alongside an Nvidia GPU?

Tags: cpu, gpu, computer-building, nvidia-geforce

Every single sales person or computer "expert" I have encountered has advised against doing a combo like this but I have bought a GTX 560 and an AMD FX-6100 and they worked fine for 5 years so far. Is there any actual detriment to this?

Comment: There is no truth to that advice.  PCI-E is PCI-E.  Nvidia and AMD both use PCI-E for all cards on the market today.

Comment: this is nonsense

Comment: This is what I thought and I did tell them that it is nonsense but they keep insisting so I just had to ask :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no detriment in using an AMD processor (CPU) with a Nvidia GPU.  As Ramhound touched on in his comment, there are standards for intercommunication between devices.

You *may* experience driver related issues when using 2 different *GPUs* in the same computer, in some cases.